# Cutkosky rules and dispersion relations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I calculated a Feynman diagram once the standard way, and once I used Cutkosky rules to get the imaginary part and then an unsubtracted dispersion relation to get the real part. The imaginary part from both methods agrees, but the real part does not agree. Can this be correct, or does the real part also have to agree since the dispersion relation was unsubtracted? Can there be a shift in values?

Comment: Is the real part divergent in the Feynman diagram caculation?

Comment: No, it is finite.

Comment: Perhaps show your work?